# OnClicked property sends data back to Go, but slot isn't invoked

Tags: qt, go, qml, signals, signals-slots

So, I am trying to write a simple login page in Qml, the user writes data in the two text fields, and once the login button is pressed the Go Slot will send some data over to another function for authentication.
The only problem is, when the login button is pressed, the slot isn't invoked, the code continues outside the main loop that creates the UI and exits the program with a SIGSEV.

**Basically going past:**

```
// Execute app
gui.QGuiApplication_Exec()
```

and exiting **MakeUI()**

**With this error**:

```
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x80 addr=0x0 pc=0x265a014]
```

**Here's my Go Code:**

```
package UI

import (
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/heyuan110/gorepertory/logger"
    "github.com/therecipe/qt/core"
    "github.com/therecipe/qt/gui"
    "github.com/therecipe/qt/qml"
    "github.com/therecipe/qt/quickcontrols2"
    "os"
)
type QmlBridge struct {
    core.QObject
    //_ func(username string,password string) bool `signal:sendToQml`
    _ func(username string,password string )bool `slot:sendToGo`
}

func MakeUI() {
    //var QmlBridgeVar *QmlBridge
    var QmlBridgeVar = NewQmlBridge(nil)

    // Create application
    app := gui.NewQGuiApplication(len(os.Args), os.Args)

    // Enable high DPI scaling
    app.SetAttribute(core.Qt__AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, true)

    // Use the material style for qml
    quickcontrols2.QQuickStyle_SetStyle("material")

    // Create a QML application engine
    engine := qml.NewQQmlApplicationEngine(nil)
    engine.RootContext().SetContextProperty("QmlBridgeVar", QmlBridgeVar)
    //QmlBridgeVar.ConnectSendToQml(func(username string,password string){
    //
    //})
    QmlBridgeVar.ConnectSendToGo(func(username string, password string){
        fmt.Println(username,password)
    })
    // Load the main qml file
    engine.Load(core.NewQUrl3("qml/main.qml", 0))
    // Execute app
    gui.QGuiApplication_Exec()
}
```

**And here's my Corresponding Qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    title: "Bouncer"
    property int margin: 11
    minimumWidth: 600
    minimumHeight: 450

    ColumnLayout {
        id: mainLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: margin
        GroupBox {
            id: rowBox
            title: "Login"
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            RowLayout {
                id: rowLayout
                anchors.fill: parent
                TextField {
                    id: usernameField
                    placeholderText: "Username"
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                }
                TextField {
                    id: passwrdField
                    placeholderText: "Password"
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                }
                Button {
                    id: loginButton
                    text: "Login"
                    MouseArea{
                        id: loginMouseArea
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        onClicked: QmlBridgeVar.sendToGo(usernameField.text, passwrdField.text)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am prone to believe I might have some problems with the Qt bindings for go? Though I am not entirely sure. If anybody can give me valuable feedback I'd highly appreciate it.

Comment: It's a plain borind nil (NULL, if you like) pointer dereference error. What happens if you put `if QmlBridgeVar == nil { panic("kaboom") }` right after the statement which initializes `QmlBridgeVar`?

Comment: @kostix The creation of QmlBridgeVar references the type definition struct above, so when it gets initialized with **NewQmlBridge(nil)** QmlBridgeVar get's populated with an QObject containing a pointer to the struct, and the slot.:  [As you can see here](https://snipboard.io/nUWJMH.jpg)

Comment: You should name the context property `qmlBridgeVar` because capitals are not allowed for the first letter of identifiers